# How to find highest odd number in an array and return 0 if no odd number is present in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, performance, testing, testng

How to find highest odd number in the array and print that to the standard output? It should return 0 if the array has no odd numbers.

I have written the program, but not getting how to return 0 in case no odd number was found in the array.

```
public class Highestodd_number {

    public int odd() {
        int[] arr = { 4, 6, 9};
        int max = arr[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] % 2 != 0 && arr[i] > max) {
                max = arr[i];
                System.out.println(max);
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Highestodd_number rt = new Highestodd_number();
        rt.odd();
    }
}
```

Comment: You *always* return 0. You need to return `max` if you've set it to an odd number.

Comment: I think you are confused about what "return 0" actually means and are confusing returning and printing a value. Because your method always returns 0, but it prints something inside the method. Your method isn't supposed to print itself, just return the value with the `return` statement.

Comment: `max` shouldn't be set to array's first element, it should be `Integer.MIN_VALUE`

Comment: return max not 0

Comment: initialize int max = 0 and return max

Comment: @karan then it fails to detect negative odd numbers

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is more a request for code review than a real question.

Comment: @MichaelPiefel Looks like there's a specific problem: "not getting how to return 0 in case no odd number in array."

Comment: @Andy Turner and @ OH GOD SPIDERS Thanks it is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to implement this task using Java 8 streams with less boilerplate code:

```java
public static int findMaxOddOr0(int[] arr) {
    return Arrays.stream(arr)               // convert array to IntStream
                 .filter(x -> x % 2 != 0)   // filter all odd values
                 .max()                     // find optional max
                 .orElse(0);                // or 0 if no max odd is found
}
    
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[][] tests = {
        {4, 6, 9},
        {2, -2, 8, 10},
        {-5, -7, -3, 12}
    };

    Arrays.stream(tests)
          .forEach(arr -> 
              System.out.printf("%s -> %d%n", Arrays.toString(arr), findMaxOddOr0(arr)));
}
```

Output:

```
[4, 6, 9] -> 9
[2, -2, 8, 10] -> 0
[-5, -7, -3, 12] -> -3
```